# Get Value From Select Option in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular4-forms

How do I get the value from the select option in Angular 4?

I want to assign it to a new variable in the component.ts file. I've tried this but outputs nothing.

Can you also do it using [(ngModel)]?

component.html

```
<form class="form-inline" (ngSubmit)="HelloCorp(f)" #f="ngForm">
     <div class="select">
         <select class="form-control col-lg-8" #corporation required>
             <option *ngFor="let corporation of corporations" [value]="corporationObj">{{corporation.corp_name}}</option>    
         </select>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary manage">Submit</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
HelloCorp() {
const corporationObj = corporation.value;
}
```

Answer (score 64):

As a general (see Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gh2rjx):

> HTML

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
   <option *ngFor="let o of options">
      {{o.name}}
   </option>
</select>
<button (click)="print()">Click me</button>

<p>Selected option: {{ selectedOption }}</p>
<p>Button output: {{ printedOption }}</p>
```

> Typescript

```
export class AppComponent {
  selectedOption: string;
  printedOption: string;

  options = [
    { name: "option1", value: 1 },
    { name: "option2", value: 2 }
  ]
  print() {
    this.printedOption = this.selectedOption;
  }
}
```

---

In your specific case you can use ngModel like this:

```
<form class="form-inline" (ngSubmit)="HelloCorp()">
     <div class="select">
         <select [(ngModel)]="corporationObj" class="form-control col-lg-8" #corporation required>
             <option *ngFor="let corporation of corporations"></option>    
         </select>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary manage">Submit</button>
     </div>
</form>

HelloCorp() {
  console.log("My input: ", corporationObj);
}
```

Comment: Is this it?  No (ngSubmit) anymore?

Comment: Yes this is it. You can use ngSubmit to trigger an event, for example:`console.log(corporationObj)`, and see your chosen input, but the corporationObj variable will change immediately, no submit needed.

Comment: Can you see my codes. I forgot to write this {{corporation.corp_name}}. This is the option values. Yours is still undefined??

Comment: My general example above should work for you. If not make sure you've both imported FormsModule and added it to your imports array in app.module.ts.

Answer (score 44):

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  items: any[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'one' },
    { id: 2, name: 'two' },
    { id: 3, name: 'three' },
    { id: 4, name: 'four' },
    { id: 5, name: 'five' },
    { id: 6, name: 'six' }
  ];
  selected: number = 1;

  constructor() {
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
  selectOption(id: number) {
    //getted from event
    console.log(id);
    //getted from binding
    console.log(this.selected)
  }

}
```

```html
<div>
  <select (change)="selectOption($event.target.value)"
  [(ngModel)]="selected">
  <option [value]="item.id" *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.name}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a code-only answer, which is not considered to be very good quality in StackOverflow. Please elaborate what this snippet does and why it helps to resolve the original issue.

Comment: Small correction: shouldn't the second line in the selectOption function be `console.log(this.selected);` (replacing "number" with "selected) ?

Answer (score 6):

You just need to put `[(ngModel)]` on your select element:

```
<select class="form-control col-lg-8" #corporation required [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
```

Comment: And how can you assign the value in the component.ts?

Answer (score 6):

> HTML code

```
    <form class="form-inline" (ngSubmit)="HelloCorp(modelName)">
        <div class="select">
            <select class="form-control col-lg-8" [(ngModel)]="modelName" required>
                <option *ngFor="let corporation of corporations" [ngValue]="corporation">
                    {{corporation.corp_name}}
                </option>    
            </select>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary manage">Submit</button>
        </div> 
    </form>
```

> Component code

```
HelloCorp(corporation) {
    var corporationObj = corporation.value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of $event. Try using the below typecast function.

> $any($event.target).value

Which will stop the type checking in the template.
You can create a function in typescript for updating corporation or directly assign to a variable.

```
<select (change) = "updateCorporation($any($event.target).value)">
    <option>Corporation1</option>    
    <option>Corporation2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is very simple actually.**

Please notice that I'm

I. adding **name="selectedCorp"** to your **select** opening tag, and

II. changing your **[value]="corporationObj"** to **[value]="corporation"**, which is consistent with the **corporation** in your *ngFor="let **corporation** of corporations" statement:

```
 <form class="form-inline" (ngSubmit)="HelloCorp(f)" #f="ngForm">
   <div class="select">
     <select class="form-control col-lg-8" #corporation name="selectedCorp" required>
       <option *ngFor="let corporation of corporations" [value]="corporation">{{corporation.corp_name}}</option>
     </select>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary manage">Submit</button>
   </div>
 </form>
```

And then in your .ts file, you just do the following:

```
HelloCorp(form: NgForm) {
   const corporationObj = form.value.selectedCorp;
}
```

and the const **corporationObj** now is **the selected corporation object**, which will include all the properties of the corporation class you have defined.

**NOTE:**

In the html code, by the statement **[value]="corporation"**, the **corporation** (from *ngFor="let **corporation** of corporations") is bound to **[value]**, and the **name** property will get the **value**.

Since the **name** is **"selectedCorp"**, you can get the actual value by getting **"form.value.selectedCorp"** in your .ts file.

By the way, actually you don't need the **"#corporation"** in your **"select"** opening tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //in html file
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Country</label>
                        <select class="form-control" formControlName="country" (change)="onCountryChange($event.target.value)">
                            <option disabled selected value [ngValue]="null"> -- Select Country  -- </option>
                            <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">{{country.name}}</option>
                            <div *ngIf="isEdit">
                                <option></option>
                            </div>
                        </select>
                      </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="help-block" *ngIf="studentForm.get('country').invalid && studentForm.get('country').touched">
                <div *ngIf="studentForm.get('country').errors.required">*country is required</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">State</label>
                        <select class="form-control" formControlName="state" (change)="onStateChange($event.target.value)">
                            <option disabled selected value [ngValue]="null"> -- Select State -- </option>
                            <option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.id">{{state.state_name}}</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="help-block" *ngIf="studentForm.get('state').invalid && studentForm.get('state').touched">
                <div *ngIf="studentForm.get('state').errors.required">*state is enter code hererequired</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">City</label>
                        <select class="form-control" formControlName="city">
                            <option disabled selected value [ngValue]="null"> -- Select City -- </option>
                            <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city.id" >{{city.city_name}}</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="help-block" *ngIf="studentForm.get('city').invalid && studentForm.get('city').touched">
                <div *ngIf="studentForm.get('city').errors.required">*city is required</div>
            </div>
    //then in component
    onCountryChange(countryId:number){
   this.studentServive.getSelectedState(countryId).subscribe(resData=>{
    this.states = resData;
   });
  }
  onStateChange(stateId:number){
    this.studentServive.getSelectedCity(stateId).subscribe(resData=>{
     this.cities = resData;
    });
   }`enter code here`
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.