# how to generate the two values in ngvalue using angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

```
<select #businesstype class="form-control" id="business_type" required [(ngModel)]="update.business_type" name="business_type" #Type="ngModel">
                                        <option disabled>Select</option>
                                    <option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.id">{{user.method}}</option>>
                                </select>
```

I have a doubt once i select the drop down is stored in id(user.id).but how to store method and id in single value.

Comment: use user directly instaed user.id ....[value]="user"

Comment: @LakshmiPrasanna you can't use `{{}}` with `[]`, use anyone at a time

Comment: @hariprasath why you want to store object into single value? can you explain bit more your question

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46447574/8670067

Answer (score 4):

Just assign an object in value:

```
[ngValue]="user"
```

or

```
[ngValue]="{id: user.id, method: user.method}"
```

**edit**

Use ngValue.

Comment: you can't use `{{}}` with `[]`, use anyone at a time, your answer will throw error for sure