# Can't get value of select in Angular 7

Tags: angular, html-select, angular7

This is my html:

```
<form class="row" (ngSubmit)="generatePdfFromOverview()" #generatePdfForm="ngForm">
    <select id="selectedSortOnItem" required [(ngModel)]="generatePdfForm.selectedSortOnItem"
        name="selectedSortOnItem" #selectedSortOnItem="ngModel">
            <option *ngFor="let sortOnItem of sortOnItems" [value]="sortOnItem">{{sortOnItem}}</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generate it!</button>
</form>
```

The values are showing fine in the view.

However the value is not updated in the .ts file when I select another one.
Tried numerous things. Followed the example in the Angular docs but does not seem to work..

Comment: Take a look at this Question, it looks similar to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447459/get-value-from-select-option-in-angular-4

Comment: change your template variable name and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was related to an issue of https://materializecss.com/

The javascript from Materialize was causing issues with the select functionality.

Upgrading to 1.0.0 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although it completely depends on your `generatePdfFromOverview` method, there are a few things that you can do to fix this issue:

Pass `generatePdfForm` to the `generatePdfFromOverview` as an argument and then use the `value` property on it to get the value of the form.

```
<form 
  class="row" 
  (ngSubmit)="generatePdfFromOverview(generatePdfForm)" 
  #generatePdfForm="ngForm">
```

And then in your Component Class:

```
generatePdfFromOverview(generatePdfForm) {
  console.log('Form Value: ', generatePdfForm.value);
}
```

This `value` is going to have a `selectedSortOnItem` property on it which is what you're looking for.

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrmj73?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.