# How to get the selected value of a select option?

Tags: angular

I would like to get the selected value of a select option in Angular 7. Two-way data binding using ngModel and I also imported FormsModule in app.module.ts.

My HTML file:

```
<select (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)" 
[(ngModel)]="optSelected"> 
 <option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.id"> 
{{opt.title}} 
</option> 
</select>
```

My TS file:

```
optSelected = 'aaa';
selectChangeHandler(event: any) {
  this.optSelected = event.target.value;
  console.log('The selected option is: ' + this.optSelected);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447459/get-value-from-select-option-in-angular-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `ngModel`/two-way data binding, instead of using the `change` event, you can simply make use of the `ngModelChange` event binding. According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#properties), it is the

> Event emitter for producing the ngModelChange event after the view
>   model updates.

```
<select (ngModelChange)="selectChangeHandler($event)" [(ngModel)]="optSelected"> 
  <option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.id"> 
    {{opt.title}} 
  </option> 
</select>
```

And on your component.ts,

```
selectChangeHandler() {
  console.log(this.optSelected);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Double checked it and it's working just fine! Thank you!