# How to get multi select dropdown selected value in angular2

Tags: angular, bootstrap-multiselect

Hi i have used Angular8 and bootstrap 4. I have used bootstrap multi-select dropdown, i need to get the selected dropdown values. How can i get those values.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qgxox1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

TS:

```
 setTimeout(() => {
      $('#multiselectFileName').multiselect({
        buttonWidth: '400px'
      });
      $('#multiselectUser').multiselect({
        buttonWidth: '400px'
      });
    },100)
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Select User</label>
          <select name="user" id="multiselectUser" multiple="multiple" (change)="selecteduser($event)">
              <option *ngFor="let field of user" [value]="field.id" >
                  {{field.userName}}</option>
          </select>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it's simular to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447459/get-value-from-select-option-in-angular-4), try to use [(ngModel)] to bind a variable of your component (ts file) in your select tag to see what happens, and also use console.log() or debug mode to view the value of the variable binding to [(ngModel)]
For example:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedUsers" name="user" id="multiselectUser" multiple="multiple" (change)="selecteduser($event)">
              <option *ngFor="let field of user" [value]="field.id" >
                  {{field.userName}}</option>
          </select>
```

Comment: Try to use *ng-container* for your *ngFor inside a select tag

`<ng-container *ngFor="let field of user">
                <option [value]="field.email">{{field.userName}}</option>
</ng-container>`
<br>
I succeeded in your Demo by the code above, you can learn this from [Doc Official](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue)